# why wrong url is extracting from my string

Tags: php, regex

If this is the string
**example**

```
     $str = 'this is a string of chars <a href="http://www.asd.com\">Anchor Text</a>';
```

i am doing this method to clean the input

```
     $res = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($str) : $str;
     $res = mysql_real_escape_string($res);
```

and this code to extract url

```
   preg_match('#href\s*?=\s*?[\'"]?([^\'"]*)[\'"]?#i', $input, $captures);                
   $href = $captures[1];
```

**But i come up with this result**

```
   "\"http://www.asd.com\""
```

string with 2 double quotes and backslash.

where i want that

http://www.asd.com

Comment: Doesn't your code trigger a parse error?

Comment: Well as first, I think you have quote errors in your string definition. You forgot a backslash before one quote.
You need this changes.
`$str = "this is a string of char's <a href=\"http://www.asd.com\">Anchor Text</a>";`

Comment: sorry i write wrong. Now i corrected it

Comment: :D now you need a backslash here: `char\'s`.

Comment: i corrected the string now check

Comment: Result with this string is same

Comment: because it's still not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, do not use regexp. It takes long to create and even longer to debug.

```
$str = 'this is a string of chars <a href="http://www.asd.com\">Anchor Text</a>';
$start = strpos($str, '<a href="') + strlen('<a href="');
$end = strpos($str, '">', $start);
substr($str, $start, $end-$start);
```

http://codepad.org/w370PJoz

Comment: and if I have `....<b>this</b> is a string of chars <a href="http://www.asd.com\">Anchor Text</a>` this well fail.

Comment: No, it did not: http://codepad.org/GspZVfWi

Comment: It will actually fail with `<a href=http://www.asd.com>Anchor Text</a>` or `<a href='http://www.asd.com'>Anchor Text</a>`and other valid HTML chunks. It's pretty useless in a more broad sense. But we can wait until the OP asks the next similar question.

Comment: Using ' or nothing is not really valid html. Sure, it works in most browsers...

Comment: @PiTheNumber: Those can be valid depending on the HTML version. `'` is commonly valid anyway, HTML and XML. That's why it works in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

> why wrong url is extracting from my string

Because the code you wrote does not execute the way you expect it to. Only because you want the code to do what you want it to do, it does not does so.

What you need to do is to write (not only want) the code the way you want it to act. That's a general thing, wanting does not work with code, but writing does.

In your case, the code has errors so that it can not execute. That's a pretty fatal thing, PHP in this case refuses to continue even.

Imagine you drive a car over a bridge because you want to reach the other side of the river.

The bridge is broken in the middle, so you drive the car into the water.

PHP is you in this case. It drives your code into nirvana, it stops like falling into the river. Everything is lost.

So the bridge needs to be fixed before you should try to drive again to the other side of the river, because you still want to and you already have learned that you felt into the water.

So you start the car in debug mode to find out where the bridge is broken. If the bridge is broken in multiple places, you would need to fix the bridge multiple times. PHP has such a debug mode which tells you about errors it runs over. If there are multiple fatal errors, it will only tell you about the first fatal error. So you might need to drive multiple times in debug mode before you can finally pass across the river.

To start PHP in debug mode, just enter the following commands at the very beginning of your script:

```
error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You can learn more about error reporting and debug related operations in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.errorfunc.php). This line will just enable reporting all kind of errors and will ensure, that errors are displayed.

Use the information displayed to you to fix the errors in your code. Again the PHP Manual contains every kind of information how to write a PHP script including information about how to format strings as well as what a specific function does, how it is called and which kind of data it returns.

Just fix every error you run over and in the end you will reach the other side of the bridge without needing the debug mode any longer. Then you can disable the debug mode and be confident that you've managed the driving safely.

Next time you run into a problem again, you know what you need to do: Just switch debug mode on again and fix the bridge.

Answer (score 1):

This code works. Correct the quotes.

```
  $str = 'this is a string of char\'s <a href="http://www.asd.com">Anchor Text</a>';
  $res = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($str) : $str;
  $res = mysql_real_escape_string($res);
  preg_match('#href\s*?=\s*?[\'"]?([^\'"]*)[\'"]?#i', $str, $captures);                
  $href = $captures[1];
  echo $href;
```

Comment: also replaced `$input` with `$str`.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions is not the way to parse an (x)html string. Use php's DOM classes:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://google.com"));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$urls = array();
foreach ($domd->getElementsByTagName("a") as $link) {
  $urls[] = $link->getAttribute("href");
}

var_dump($urls);
```

This will create and dump an array that contains all the href attributes in the original string (in this case, google.com).