# wrong url extraction

Tags: php, regex, extract

I am getting input from user on my site through a text area. the input may contain <a> TAG.
I want to extract the url from the input.

```
$res = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($data) : $data;
$res = mysql_real_escape_string($res); // php 4.3 and higher                
preg_match('#href\s*?=\s*?[\'"]?([^\'"]*)[\'"]?#i', $res, $captures);                
$href = $captures[1];
```

**example**

if **Input** sting is this?

```
$data = 'any string <a href="http://www.example.com">Any Anchor</a>';
```

the extracted **output** becomes

```
"\"http://www.example.com""
```

i checked the output after each line, 2 double quotes comes after

```
mysql_real_escape_string($res);
```

Comment: Don't call `mysql_real_escape_string` then…?

Comment: I told you some questions ago, don't copy over and over `$res = mysql_real_escape_string($res); // php 4.3 and higher` because you don't need it. And it's highly likely that you don't need as well `$res = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($data) : $data;` because magic quotes is disabled nowadays.

Comment: And instead of the tedious magic quotes checking, solve that problem *once* with one of the example functions from http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [why wrong url is extracting from my string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561878/why-wrong-url-is-extracting-from-my-string)

Answer (score 2):

**`mysql_real_escape_string` should only AND ALWAYS be used when passing user values into MySQL queries**. Don't use it for anything else, use the right escaping function for the right task.

Here, I don't think you need to use an escape function at all. Your regular expression looks fine, I'm confident it will work if you remove the escaping function.

Also, don't use `get_magic_quotes_gpc` if you can avoid it. I could explain why but I suppose the fact that it's been deprecated since PHP5.0 is evidence enough. If your host does not allow you to disable it I would consider switching to a more savvy host.

Comment: I need mysql_real_escape_string function because i am sending data to Database and also screen same time using ajax

Comment: Escape it when you put it into your query, not before, not after.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try processing the input using XPath to find the a elements and then extract the href attribute value. I did something similar and used XPath in order to process input and it worked a treat. Saves you having to write very complex regex expressions if you would like to account for other tags later on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would strongly advise against this because it requires your HTML to be valid XML (or XHTML). I know some frameworks do this, perhaps it's a matter of taste, but I believe you incur a heavy penalty for no practical benefit. If you can not inherently give the guarantee that your HTML is valid XHTML, don't do it, otherwise .. go for it?

Comment: Point taken ... didn't think about that. In a blacklisting approach all user input is considered malicious anyway, so it would be somewhat silly to assume that the input will be valid XML.

Comment: Well, you could reject user input if it isn't valid XHTML in an earlier validation step, which is fine if your WYSIWYG guarantees to produce valid XHTML as well.